# How to import git java project to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

I've tried every option explained  step by step [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760115/importing-a-github-project-into-eclipse) [and here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245924/import-java-project-from-github-to-eclipse) [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070017/how-to-import-a-git-non-eclipse-java-project-into-eclipse)

And I can't get it to work.

What I want to do is pick [this project:](https://github.com/Simmetrics/simmetrics) , however it may be done (I've tried both through maven and git), and use its code in eclipse. And what I mean by that, is that I get to the point of seeing the folders in eclipse, but I can't create packages since it's not a java project, and if I mess up the code on the files that appear, it doesn't give me a warning nor in general interacts with said code.

So I guess I'm missing some piece of knowledge and I don't know where else to look for it. **What should I do to use that project in my eclipse, and create my own code that calls and uses the classes and methods from said project?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since this artifact is present in the maven repository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.mpkorstanje/simmetrics/4.1.1), you can create your own new maven project in Eclipse and add simmetrics as a dependency to it in its pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.mpkorstanje</groupId>
  <artifactId>simmetrics</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This will put simmetrics to the classpath of your own project and you should be able use its API

Answer (score 1):

Just download it with git, then import it as a maven project. If this fails, create  new "java project from existing sources", pointing as a source the simmetrics-core/src and simmetrics-example/src directories. If it fails, point separately simmetrics-core/src/main, simmetrics-core/src/test etc.

Comment: I have tried the first option, the second one seems promising, thanks for the help.