# import existing java project to use with python

Tags: java, python, eclipse, git, import

I am trying to use an existing Java project from github and write a 'wrapper' to let it interface with my larger python-based project. However I am a little rusty with java and have never been very strong with project setup.

What is the best way to do this?

What I am currently trying is I have created a separate java project in the same workspace in Eclipse, and I am trying to just get the java code to work by itself for now. I am having difficulty importing and making use of the existing project in a non-kludgey way. I could just copy and paste the files in, but am trying to use best practises and am not sure what that is.

The project from github is https://github.com/USPTO/PatentPublicData and I am just trying to get it to work with the sample code from the PatentDocument README.

Comment: So, the python tag is just telling us when you get the Java working you might user it from python later? When you say "copy and paste the files in" have you cloned the git repo and got the files locally? Or are you trying to manually copy them off the github page? If so, clone the repo first - then look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245924/import-java-project-from-github-to-eclipse

Comment: Or, can you make it work in its own workspace, but can import to your existin gone?

Comment: I had cloned it locally. I was able to import it as a maven project and have it not show errors, however I still cannot figure out an elegant way to use it in my project.

Comment: I think learning maven and proper java project structure is beyond the scope of this project. I am going to just copy the source files into my project